# Where to buy cheap secondhand samue and yukata in Tokyo?

Tags: budget, japan, shopping, tokyo

I will be next few days in Tokyo (Shinjuku area) and I want to buy secondhand [samue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samue) and a [yukata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukata). Anyone can recommend something?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?  Samue are traditional men's working clothes, they're completely different from women's kimono.  An actual kimono requires trained assistance to put on, so you're probably much better off buying a yukata.

Comment: Yes, until you decide what you atually want (kimono or samue) I will vote to close this. it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I'm guessing bluszcz is using the word "kimono" first in the naive western sense of most non-Japanophiles who don't know the difference between a kimono, a samue, and a yukata. Then, for those who do know the difference, uses the accurate term. I see no reason to close the question.

Comment: Ok, to specify I am looking for samue, but also yukata. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would try the [Hanazono Shrine Antique Market](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/japan/tokyo/shopping/other/hanazono-jinja-flea-market) in Shinjuku. In addition to kimonos they offer used books, hanging scroll art, prints, and accessories.  Like anything secondhand it can be hit-or miss on what is available when you are there.

Alternatively if you are willing to travel a bit (4.5 hours) the [Kimono Flea Market Ichiroya](http://www.ichiroya.com/) is one of the best places to buy a genuine secondhand kimono in Japan. To get an idea of what to expect they have a really good [eBay store](http://www.ebay.com/usr/ichiroya) that you can browse.

**Hanazono Shrine Antique Market Schedule**
Every Sun (Closed on Shrine activity days and rainy days)
Open hours: Sunrise - sunset
Address: Hanazono-jinja shrine grounds, 5-17-3 Shinjuku Shinjuku-ku

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately when I was there it was closed...  Finally bought them in Kyoto. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

http://www.chicago.co.jp/kimono.html#in%20english

Thrift store called Chicago, they have a large selection of kimono and yukata; I went to the one in Kyoto 3 years ago and bought 3 beautiful pieces at reasonable price :)  In Tokyo go the the CHICAGO – Omotesando. More info: http://jennysretro.com/vintage-shopping-guides/retro-guide/

Answer (score 1):

Yukatas are reasonably inexpensive. I bought one first-hand off-the-rack at an ordinary clothing store in Izu Inatori just before a festival. I can't remember exactly how much mine was, but it was comparable with the cost of an ordinary piece of western-style clothing. You don't need to buy one second-hand for cost reasons unless you're really watching the pennies.

(If you want to see it, go to slides 55 and 56 of [Travel Night: Japan](http://www.slideshare.net/agrimm/yha-japan-travel-night-internet-version-27126183))

Wikivoyage's guide to [Purchasing a kimono](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Purchasing_a_kimono) (which covers other Japanese clothing than actual kimonos) says that there isn't much of a second-hand market for yukatas:

> Yukata make good souvenirs and gifts because they are more practical
>   and easier to wear than kimono. However, people tend to hang onto
>   these precisely for that reason, and therefore there's less of a
>   second hand market.