# Where to buy zafu (can be secondhand) in Tokyo or Kyoto

Tags: japan, shopping, tokyo, kyoto

Tomorrow I will be travelling to Tokyo, and later to Kyoto. I am interested in buying a new or secondhand [zafu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zafu), which is a special cushion for [zazen meditation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zazen).

[I already asked a similar question (but regarding Samue)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22897/where-to-buy-cheap-secondhand-kimono-samue-in-tokyo). I tried to search around, but didn't manage to get any confirmation that they can be bought in same areas.

Comment: I am already here, and it seems it is super difficult to buy - I was asking around few days, and nobody had idea :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for a pretty obscure bit of kit, most Zen temples I've been to in Japan frown on frippery like comfortable cushions for meditation.  But you should be able to find these in a well-stocked Buddhist goods store, and here are a couple with an online presence that claim to have them in stock:

- [Butsudanya Takita Shoten](http://www.butsudanya.co.jp) (仏壇屋 滝田商店), Kotobuki 2-8-11, Taito, Tokyo, near the famed Sensoji Temple in Asakusa.  [This bad boy](http://store.shopping.yahoo.co.jp/takita/jiin0501-03.html) is Y4510, and they've got others as well.
- Negishi Futon (根岸ふとん店), this is actually a small chain but one outlet is in Nozawa 2-5-23, Setagaya, Tokyo.  [Y9800 for this set of two](http://www.myoshin-zen-c.jp/c_record/my_zabuton/index.htm), which is apparently the Official Meditation Cushion(tm) of the Rinzai Zen sect and is used by the [Tokyo Zen Center](http://www.myoshin-zen-c.jp/).

Alternatively, if you're actually planning to [study meditation in Japan](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Meditation_in_Japan), I'm sure the temples can either hook you up or sell you one directly.

Comment: Finally a master of temple where I stayed ordered me online in Asakusa shop and delivered to hotel. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Matsumotoya](http://www.matsumotoya.com/) in Kyoto [sells zafu](http://www.matsumotoya.com/shop/products/detail.php?product_id=186), though the selection is quite limited.

I can't really tell if this is a physical storefront or solely an online presence, even after looking at [Street View](http://goo.gl/maps/bTW9v), though it should be easy enough to [contact them](http://www.matsumotoya.com/shop/abouts/index.php) and find out. In the latter case, it shouldn't be difficult to arrange for delivery.

Answer (score 2):

Butsudanya Takita Shoten is under construction at the moment. Near Tawaramachi station there is a line of Budsudanya shops, I found the zazen zabuton in one of them, but there is need to ask, I didn't see any at the shop window. [Here is the streetview image of the shops.](https://www.google.co.jp/maps/@35.709811,139.790734,3a,75y,240.08h,79.79t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sSmW0Ccgb5VUIZmtHi-hKNQ!2e0!6m1!1e1)